# Rails / Ruby how to always show decimal precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, decimal

I am currently converting some python statistics library that needs to produce a number with high decimal precision. For example, I did this:

```
i = 1
n = 151
sum = (i - 3/8) / (n + 1/4)
```

it will result to 0.

My question is how to always show decimal precision automatically when I do this kind of computation?

My desired output is:
**0.004132231404958678**

Comment: You're using integers (FixNum). Try computing using BigDecimal.

Answer (score 5):

In ruby all the arithmetic operations result in the value of the same type as operands (the one having better precision.)

That said, `3/4` is an *integer* division, resulting in `0`.

To make your example working, you are to ensure you are not losing precision anywhere:

```
i = 1.0
n = 151.0
sum = (i - 3.0/8) / (n + 1/4.0)
```

Please note, that as in most (if not all) languages, `Float` is tainted:

```
0.1 + 0.2 #⇒ 0.30000000000000004
```

If you need *an exact* value, you might use [`BigDecimal`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) or [`Rational`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html).